# I used str() on string with byte literal, how do I reverse the operation?

Tags: python

So I had binary like the following `b"My name is ...\n blah blah"` then I used I used `str()` on it which resulted in `"b'My name is ...\\n blah blah'"` how can I undo this and get a variable with byte literal again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = literal_eval("b'My name is ...\\n blah blah'")
>>> s
b'My name is ...\n blah blah'
```

Comment: To be clear: While this works, it's not super-fast, and if you have code that converts to and from `bytes` `repr`s by design (it's not just some way to recover data you accidentally converted the wrong way), you almost certainly have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). Production code should not be relying on this conversion.